# Jenkins REST api continues to return the reload page after a call to reload

Tags: jenkins

After making a call to 
`curl -s -X POST -H ${CRUMB} -u user:token "http://jenkinsserver/reload"`

The next several subsequent curl calls return a variant of the Jenkins reload wait page. Eventually curl starts working as expected again. What is happening and how can I make my program deterministic again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Jenkins reloads from disk it returns a 'wait for reload' page to all http requests.  To wait for Jenkins to start responding to requests again, use something like the following bash code.  The crumb request was used as a simple Jenkins request.  Any other request would do.

```
curl -s -X POST -H ${CRUMB} -u user:token "http://jenkinsurl/reload"

    #Give Jenkins time to reload
    CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://user:token@jenkinsurl/crumbIssuer/api/xml?\
    xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
    while echo ${CRUMB} | grep reload; do
        echo "Waiting for reload to complete"
        sleep 10
        CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://user:token@jenkinsurl/crumbIssuer/api/xml?\
        xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
    done
```